# parse javascript get html results for page title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing, get

Need to snag page title and other meta from jQuery's `$.get` results. Read somewhere on here (can't seem to find the question though - sorry!) that it only returns elements within `body`.  That said, if I log the results to the console I see a massive array of data that includes the title and meta tags.

**So the question is simple- how can I navigate the array to pull out the title?**

Here's an example. The below example returns `content` as an HTML object, but `title` returns undefined. Makes sense if only the `body` is returned. That said, logging `data` prints the [entire pages HTML](http://cloud.dhut.ch/image/061t263x0K09) from top to bottom. Logging `thiis` prints the [page as an array](http://cloud.dhut.ch/image/0Z2p1k0X163c), where I can see an entry for `title`, whose `innerHTML` has the page title. So -
*how should `title`'s value be assigned?*

Thanks for your help!

JavaScript

```
$.get(target, function(data){

    var thiis   = $(data),
        content = thiis.find('#pageMain'),
        title   = thiis.find('title');

    console.log(data, thiis);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery does not parse the doctype, html, head, and body elements. It sets your whole page that you retireved with the GET request as the innerHTML of a div. You only get back a collection of the resulting element so the title element and id of pageMin are not able to be found with find(). You would need to use filter().

```
$.get(target, function(data){
    var nodes   = $(data),
        content = nodes.filter('#pageMain'),
        title   = nodes.filter('title');
    console.log(content,title);
});
```

In order to use find() you would need to set the innerHTML of a div with the data and query off that parent node.

Comment: Got it- any reason this is more efficient than @scrappedcola's answer below?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the returned data in a div first then make your selection.

```
$.get(target, function(data){
    var $wrap = $("<div></div>").append(data);
    var title = $wrap.find("title");
});
```